# JavaFX is working but the try-catch-finally code isn't

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I just started my lesson about exception handling and I'm unsure of what I did wrong in my code -- what I'm aiming to do is to create a UI that asks the user how many pets they own, and checks if the input is an integer. Can anyone point out what's wrong?

I've already tried using label.setText() for my message, and I've also changed the exception I used (I tried NumberFormat).

Here's the block I used (this is the first time I encountered EH, so I find this topic kind of confusing)

```
String value = input.getText();                                  
int intval = 0;
intval = Integer.parseInt(value);
try {
    if (0 >= intval) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else 
        throw new InputMismatchException();
}

catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
    String outputMessage = "The number must be an integer no less than 0!";
    label1.setText(outputMessage);
}

catch(InputMismatchException i) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    System.out.println("You entered: " + intval);
}

finally
{ 
    System.out.println("You own " + intval + " pets.");
}
```

The exceptions I want to include are if the user entered another number type instead of an integer, and if the user entered a negative integer instead of a positive one or 0. My code runs, but the try-catch block doesn't really work.

Comment: `but the try-catch block doesn't really work` Can you elaborate? Whot do you expect and what happens? Also there's no reason to throw exceptions in your code, you can simply execute the code in the `if-else`

Comment: You already convert the string input to an integer **before** the try block, so anything other than an int will have already thrown a NumberFormatException. Your code will only work as you intended for negative integers, it won't work for non-integers.

Comment: Hi! I made this code for a javafx window, so what I meant by it wasn’t working was that when I clicked on the submit button to check if the user input was valid it wasn’t showing/ displaying the messages. My aim here was to use expections for checking the input, so I can’t really use if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are lot of defects in this code! First of all you shouldn't have taken the input as String if you would have taken the input as integer you could have raised the InputMismatchException by which you could have easily told the user saying "enter only integer value", by taking input as the string you will not be able to do that.
Don't use finally block, because no matter how many exceptions are throw by your code the finally block will get executed. Even if you entered -1 at last(while executing the code) it will show "you have -1 pets:" message, as finally block gets executed not matter what happens!
I refactored the code to make it work the same way

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean exceptionHit = false;

        int value = 0;

        try {
            value = input.nextInt();
            if (value <= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            String outputMessage = "The number must be an integer no less than 0!";
            label1.setText(outputMessage);
            exceptionHit = true;

        } catch (InputMismatchException i) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
            exceptionHit = true;
        }
        if (exceptionHit == false)
        System.out.println("You have " + value + " pets");
```

I have removed finally block so the last message will not be displayed every time! I have added a boolean value instead of it which will be set to true if any exception is hit.

Comment: While this is helpful for Java only, the question is asking about JavaFx, and have left out some details, such as OP is most likely using a `TextField` to gain input.